# Cannot use external identities in Azure AD portal (aad.portal.azure.com)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b

The newly released feature of `External Identities` in Azure AD is accessible from `https://portal.azure.com` but not from `https://aad.portal.azure.com`.  When we go to user flows blade or user attributes blade, the blade behaves differently.

Answer (score 1):

It was a CORS issue. Microsoft has fixed the issue and now customers can use aad.portal.azure.com